# How to split an URL in Java

Tags: java, android, url

Hello i have an URL i get from the Server:

http://localhost.osc-ref.dockercloud.fiducia.de/login?code=11448259-7efe-4c6e-bbce-216bb8578bd5&scope=openid&iss=https%3A%2F%2Fr8840-e40-e.t1.web.fiducia.de%3A443%2Fservices_my-account%2Foauth2%2FXC8840&state=myScope&client_id=fkp

What i need now is from the Query to get the "**code**" which is this part 11448259-7efe-4c6e-bbce-216bb8578bd5, how to i split this String so to get only the code or other parameters using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the value for query param `code`.

```
String url = "http://localhost.osc-ref.dockercloud.fiducia.de/login?code=11448259-7efe-4c6e-bbce-216bb8578bd5&scope=openid&iss=https%3A%2F%2Fr8840-e40-e.t1.web.fiducia.de%3A443%2Fservices_my-account%2Foauth2%2FXC8840&state=myScope&client_id=fkp";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
Log.e("Value for query-param:", code);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked exactly how i wanted it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.utils.URLEncodedUtils

String url = "http://www.example.com/something.html? 
one=1&two=2&three=3&three=3a";

List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), 
Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
     System.out.println(param.getName() + " : " + param.getValue());
}
```